# Concatenation of dynamic integer with id

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a project and this is the relevant code for the problem

```
function calldiv(c)
{
    $("modal_dialog").dialog({
        title: "Approach with your deal",
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('destroy')
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });

}
```

Here what I want is to attach value of c with modal_dialog on runtime i.e if c = 1 then next line becomes modal_dialog1 .
Thanks

Comment: Next line means ??. Can you explain what you want

Comment: $("modal_dialog" + c).dialog({ ... }) ?

Answer (score 0):

Concat `c` with the string used to target `modal_dialog`:

```
function calldiv(c)
{
    $("modal_dialog"+c).dialog({
        title: "Approach with your deal",
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('destroy')
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });

}
```